# Access class properties outside of mqtt callback scope

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scope, mqtt

I am using [npm-mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) to get data from another mqtt broker.

On each message received I want to add the data to the class/component array property.

But I cannot access the class or its properties. Instead the scope says I am in the mqtt client class object.

Here is a code example:

```
this.mydata: Array<any> = [];

private fetchWithMqtt(){
var client = mqtt.connect('ws://' + this.ip + ":" + Number(this.port) + "/mqtt");
        // set callback handlers
        client.on('close', this.onConnectionLost);
        client.on('message', this.onMessageArrived);
        client.on('connect', this.onConnect);
}

private onMessageArrived(topic, message) {
        let tempDataset = JSON.parse(message).dataset;
            this.mydata.push({ //this.mydata is undefined because this = mqtt-client
                x: tempDataset[0],
                y: tempDataset[1]
            });
```

How can I push data to my class property outside this scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), you can make sure `this` doesn't change when your events are called.

Your code will now look like:

```
this.mydata: Array<any> = [];

private fetchWithMqtt(){
    var client = mqtt.connect('ws://' + this.ip + ":" + Number(this.port) + "/mqtt");
    // set callback handlers
    client.on('close', this.onConnectionLost.bind(this));
    client.on('message', this.onMessageArrived.bind(this));
    client.on('connect', this.onConnect.bind(this));
}

private onMessageArrived(topic, message) {
    let tempDataset = JSON.parse(message).dataset;
    this.mydata.push({
        x: tempDataset[0],
        y: tempDataset[1]
    });
```

But what if you need to access the `client` within the event handler? Well then you can still use bind, but prepend `mydata` to the event handler and take it in as an argument.

Your code now becomes:

```
this.mydata: Array<any> = [];

private fetchWithMqtt(){
    var client = mqtt.connect('ws://' + this.ip + ":" + Number(this.port) + "/mqtt");
    // set callback handlers
    client.on('close', this.onConnectionLost.bind(client, this.mydata));
    client.on('message', this.onMessageArrived.bind(client, this.mydata));
    client.on('connect', this.onConnect.bind(client, this.mydata));
}

private onMessageArrived(mydata, topic, message) {
    let tempDataset = JSON.parse(message).dataset;
    mydata.push({ // this == client
        x: tempDataset[0],
        y: tempDataset[1]
    });
```

Comment: Your 2nd approach is a copy by reference and not by value? Otherwise this won't work as intended.

Comment: My second approach does pass `this.mydata` by reference and at the time of reference `this` is still your class instance, not mqtt. So it's just prepending `this.mydata` to whatever call but the current context when the event triggers does not matter because we're always prepending the same array. I'd go with the first solution as often as possible, but if you needed access to the client for some reason I wanted to make sure to post a workaround.